# Modifying given variables in ASM

Tags: function, variables, assembly, x86

This is the ASM code:

```
__declspec(naked) void foo(something* t)
{
__asm {
push    ebp
mov ebp, esp
mov eax, dword ptr [t]
mov dword ptr [eax], 0
mov dword ptr [eax+4], 0
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
}
```

This would be the C version of the code:

```
struct something {
_int64 a;
_int64 b;
_int64 c;
};

void foo(struct* something) {
something->a = 0;
}
```

Now, I am wonder if I could do the same thing without storing t in eax. And just use ebp instead. But I am not sure where "a" would be (ebp+28 or ebp), and if it is even possible. This doesn't seem to work. Does anyone if this is possible, and how?

```
mov     dword ptr [ebp+28], 0
mov     dword ptr [ebp+24], 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Arbitrary nesting of expressions is not possible in assembly. That's what high level languages were invented for. In other words, yes, you have to load the value of `t` into a register if you want to dereference it. Assembly does not support constructs like

```
mov     dword ptr [[ebp+28]], 0
```

which is what you're aiming for. `ebp+28` is not the address of `t->a`; it's the address of `t`, which is the address of `t->a`.

Also, the assembly snippet zeros out both `t->a` and `t->b` while the C one only does `a`. They're not equivalent.